# Is CAST5-CBC as supported by OpenSSL an authenticated encryption method?

Tags: authentication, cryptography, openssl

I'm looking to encrypt some files using a simple cipher plugin. I have access to using AES-256 in CBC mode, but this doesn't offer message authentication and I'd have to build my own HMAC for it.

CAST5-CBC is one of my options. Is CAST5 in CBC mode an authenticated encryption method or do I still have to build my own authentication into it? AES-GCM is unavailable to me, sadly, as I would use that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason AES-CBC isn't an authenticated mode has everything to do with the CBC and nothing to do with the AES. CAST5-CBC isn't inherently authenticated either; changing one bit in the IV changes the corresponding bit in the first block, and there's no way to detect it, because that's a result of the CBC construction and not of the cipher.

Comment: Ah, so it's the block mode, right. I'm wondering why the Ruby OpenSSL library I'm using isn't up to date and doesn't show support for GCM.